# Fatal error Magento 2: On product page HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, product-page, magento2.3.1, http-error-500

On the product page this error is showing
Magento 2.3.1 ultimo theme 
What to do please help?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean in /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/AbstractBlock.php:160 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/Logo.php(116): Infortis\Brands\Block\AbstractBlock->getBrand(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/Logo.php(103): Infortis\Brands\Block\Logo->getCurrentBrand() 

#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1036): Infortis\Brands\Block\Logo->getCacheKeyInfo() 

#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1094): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getCacheKey() 

#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(661): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() 

#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() 

#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\ in /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/AbstractBlock.php on line 160
```

Answer (score 0):

time to time I become a genius yes yes I am modest
I solved this problem by reconfiguring the ((Default Label)) of brand attribute to its original name (Manufacturer)
So if you change one change the other too (if you changed Default Label change the name of brand attribute)

[image: Fatal error Magento 2: On product page HTTP ERROR 500]